# Sqlite spec: 4.2. Type Conversions Prior To Comparison

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

Based on Sqlite docs: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_conversions_prior_to_comparison, especially this statement:

> If one operand has INTEGER, REAL or NUMERIC affinity and the other operand has TEXT or BLOB or no affinity then NUMERIC affinity is applied to other operand.

I would expect the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id integer primary key, str varchar(20));
INSERT INTO t (id, str) VALUES (1, '5'), (2, '5u');

SELECT id, 5 = str, 5 >= str, CAST(5 AS NUMERIC) >= str, CAST(str AS NUMERIC) FROM t;
```

to return `5 >= str` = `1` for both rows as the left side operand has NUMERIC affinity.

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e9c19/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be missing [this part](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr):

> with the CAST operator the conversion always takes place *even if the conversion lossy and irreversible*, whereas column affinity only changes the data type of a value if the change is lossless and reversible

(emphasis mine).

Comment: Thank you, yes, that is probably the missing part :)